# Can I transfer photos that are not in my iPhone's camera roll to my computer?

Tags: ios, photos

My iPhone was linked to my main computer and it has all my photos stored on it, but not in the camera roll. Since my husband blew the main computer up, my precious photos appear to be in limbo. It does not appear that I can import them anywhere. I could email all them one by one but that seems a little low tech. iTunes tells me that if I upgrade iOS I will lose my photos that are not in the camera roll. Also, the same would seem to be true if I deauthorize my main (now usless) PC. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get the photos back on your computer that you synced to your iPhone. However, they will be a lower quality as iTunes automatically resizes them when it syncs them onto your device.

One way to copy photos off an iDevice is through a program called [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) (previously iPhone Explorer) that lets you access some of the filesystem on the iPhone.

Install the program from the [website](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), then open it. You will be presented with a screen where you should find your iPhone listed. Here are the locations of the photos:

Camera Roll Photos:
iPhone -> Media -> DCIM

Previously Synced Photos:
iPhone -> Media -> PhotoData - > Sync

To get the synced photos off your iPhone drag the Sync folder into a folder on your computer and wait for them to copy. The same applies to the camera roll photos if you want to grab them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late but I've just had this problem, but I have an easy fix (providing you have another iOS device capable of AirDrop. I selected all the photos from the iPhone that were synced from the computer (it did take a few minutes but it's self explanatory) and I sent them to my iPad via AirDrop - thus saving the photos onto the camera roll of my iPad, from where you can plug your ipad into your computer, and import the photos that way!

Answer (score 0):

One process to get access to synced photos is to duplicate them so they appear in camera roll. The process is lossless. This way you can access these photos in well known ways.

The process is described in this answer: [How to convert synced photo folders to camera roll folders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/how-to-convert-synced-photo-folders-to-camera-roll-folders#200617)

Basically you open the folder with the synced images, select all of them, then tap on share icon and then tap "Duplicate".

Answer (score -1):

After lot of crazy efforts to find a solution to this my brother finally got a way.. download an app called send anywhere on both the devices.. that is your iphone as well as the place you want to send the pics to.. you need good internet connectivity and voila you have your photos transferred in some time to their final destination :P :D

Comment: Could you add a link to the app you are recommending?

Answer (score -1):

There are file browsing apps you can use. They will scan the whole file system on your phone and list all the photos on the device. FoneTrans is a quite nice one to do that though the user interface is a bit ugly.

Tutorial: [How to Transfer Photos from iPhone to Computer](http://www.iphonetransferrecovery.com/tutorials/transfer-photos-from-iphone-to-mac.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer a little bit?

Comment: It's helpful to provide links to apps and explain how it solves the OP's question.

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes you can transfer data from iOS to iTunes or icloud . And  you need to download iTunes and iCloud on your PC .Then singing in with your Apple ID and stuffBut .If you want to transfer data from iOS to computer quickly. How to deal it ? You maybe need an easy-to-use iOS transfer tool .

Answer (score -4):

There is no change you can make photos from nothing.
You should recover them before transfer them.
Also, check iCloud to see if they were there. If you've backed once on iTunes or iCloud, you may find them there.
If you insisted, you may check this guide for further information:
[How to Transfer Photos from iPhone to Computer](http://transferphone.com/iphone-photos-to-computer.html)

Answer (score -4):

I think you can not transfer the photos like in camera roll to your computer. You can try iCloud.