# How can I import photos not in the camera roll from iPad to mac?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, photos.app, photos

The photos in my iPad is synced from iPhoto in my mac, so they are not in the camera roll. But unfortunately I formatted my drive so the iPhoto library in my mac is gone. Now all the photo is in my iPad, but it seems no convenient way to get them out. I hope I can keep all the file name correct.

Comment: I think this answer may also help you. I use the same product... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31235/can-i-transfer-photos-that-are-not-in-my-iphones-camera-roll-to-my-computer?rq=1

Comment: I would love to. But it seems that I cannot accept a comment since it's not an "answer"?

Comment: No worries, glad it helped