# Recover pictures deleted by syncing iPhone from different photo library

Tags: iphone

Today while I was trying to transfer pictures from computer to my iPhone, I selected the folder I wanted to copy then a message appeared on the screen that

> Photos synced to iPhone from other photo libraries or folders will be removed and photos will be synced from this computer. Photos taken from iPhone will not affected.

I entered the option Remove and Sync.

Now the older pictures have been deleted and the new one's have been added.

How can I recover the older picture?

Comment: I don't think you can recover photos deleted from clicking "Remove and Sync", but for people that find this topic through Google and are wondering if there is any way to get the pictures off of their phone, I was able to find an article that mentions how to do it, see [my answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379585/199491).

Answer (score 2):

iDevices can only by synced to one computer running iTunes.
Syncing to a new computer/iTunes will erase all previous data.

If you still have the other computer that the iPhone was last synced to, then you might be able to retrieve them from your last backup. Alternatively, check your iCloud storage.

It would have been far safer to click Cancel & instead copy the previous photos to the computer using Photos.app or Image Capture, Mac or Photo Gallery [part of MS Essentials], PC.

Comment: With the exception of Photo Gallery (which seems to be not supported anymore), I wasn't able to find any of the programs you mentioned; do you have a link you can give me to these programs or any more information about them? (e.g., company that made them, or something like that?)

Comment: They're both built-in Mac apps