# Copying old photos from an iPhone to a PC

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, photos, photos.app

A couple years ago, I switched from Android to iPhone 7 Plus. The person helping me at the Sprint store transferred all my photos from Android phone onto their computer, and then to my iPhone.

I need to get these photos off of my iPhone, but they don't show up in iTunes, and neither in my iCloud. What can I do other than sending myself hundreds of emails with the photos attached?

Comment: Do the photos show in the Photos app on your iPhone (the app whose full name is "Photos" and nothing else), or did the Sprint person screw up and put them somewhere else?

Comment: They do show up when i open the photos app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to view the photos in Photos app, an easier approach would to use a cloud storage service such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) or [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/).

Just create a free account with either one of them, install the iOS client app. Both the apps offer photo sync service where they upload the contents of Camera roll onto their server.

Once you have all the photos backed up, you can simply install the client app on your PC and sync off the photos to your computer.

- [Dropbox - iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/dropbox/id327630330)
- [Google Drive - iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-drive/id507874739)

Comment: So far it seems that the dropbox route is the way i'm going to go.  Google Drive wasn't getting the old photos, just the recent ones that i had taken with this phone. Thank you for the help!  I dont know why i didn't think of dropbox, i've used it plenty of times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to duplicate these transferred (aka. synced) photos. This makes them appear in camera roll and then you can access these photos in well known ways.

The process of duplication is described in this answer: [How to convert synced photo folders to camera roll folders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/how-to-convert-synced-photo-folders-to-camera-roll-folders#200617)

Basically you open the folder with the synced images, select all of them, then tap on share icon and then tap "Duplicate".