# Import Albums "From my Mac" to my iPhone albums and keep them synced

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, photos, album

I don't use iCloud Photos. I wanted to import my iPhone photo albums to my Mac but it seems that without iCloud Photos it is not possible without any third party software according to my searches.

But I've found that I can create albums on Photos on my Mac and then sync with my iPhone. So I took time to recreate albums on my Mac. I factory reset my iPhone and then sync with my Mac. All the photos are back, even the albums, great.

BUT, the albums on my iPhone are "hidden" in the "From my Mac" section. Not in "My Albums". And I can't add photos to these albums on my iPhone. I could select all the photos and add them on a newly created album on my iPhone with the same name but.. I guess it will be out of sync.

**Is it possible to keep the albums between my Mac and iPhone synced AND have the possibility to add photos to these albums on my iPhone ? Without iCloud Photos.**

I've searched for a solution for the past two days and I don't know what to do anymore.
It is supposed to be simple.. isn't it ? :(

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is of any help to your particular issue and does not answer your question but did you know that you can duplicate these synced photos to camera roll, see here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/how-to-convert-synced-photo-folders-to-camera-roll-folders#200617
After the photos appear on the camera roll, you can edit and delete them. To keep them in sync with the originals on your computer is a different challenge.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. After Google stopped backing up photos for free I've decided to subscribe to iCloud to manage my photos so I don't have this problem anymore. But I didn't find any solution for this problem for someone who doesn't have an iCloud sub

Answer (score 0):

Ok technically I've found the answer : no.

It seems that due to iOS limitations, you can't edit album that are created outside the iPhone.

So I'll try to achieve my goal by managing photos manually.

The problem is : Photos crashes during the export. I'll ask another question for that.